# Sign In with Apple: How to achieve it for existing app?

Tags: ios, apple-sign-in

With recent major updates released by Apple on 3rd June 2019, there is one feature [Sign In with Apple](https://developer.apple.com/sign-in-with-apple/get-started/). Information about 'how to use this' in app is available but I can see any sample source code, how to achieve this feature in your existing iOS app.

I'm looking for a sample source code, as I can't understand how to start with this.

And what I've tried: [Sign In with Apple](https://developer.apple.com/sign-in-with-apple/get-started/)

Comment: Here the article for the same - https://developerinsider.co/ios-13-how-to-integrate-sign-in-with-apple-in-your-application/ 

.... A working demo with keychain integration available on Github https://github.com/developerinsider/Sign-In-with-Apple-Demo

Comment: Sample code is available [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/adding_the_sign_in_with_apple_flow_to_your_app). Keep in mind that while the vast majority of users upgrade to the newest release of iOS, you should consider supporting Sign in With Apple on previous releases by using the JS API.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First step is you need to `import AuthenticationServices`

### How to check that user credential state

```
        let appleIDProvider = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider()
        appleIDProvider.getCredentialState(forUserID: KeychainItem.currentUserIdentifier) { (credentialState, error) in
            switch credentialState {
            case .authorized:
                // The Apple ID credential is valid.
                break
            case .revoked:
                // The Apple ID credential is revoked.
                break
            case .notFound:
                // No credential was found, so show the sign-in UI.
               
            default:
                break
            }
        }
```

### How to create Login with Apple

**Step1**

Prompts the user if an existing iCloud Keychain credential or Apple ID credential is found. implement `ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate` to

```
func performExistingAccountSetupFlows() {
    // Prepare requests for both Apple ID and password providers.
    let requests = [ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider().createRequest(),
                    ASAuthorizationPasswordProvider().createRequest()]
    
    // Create an authorization controller with the given requests.
    let authorizationController = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: requests)
    authorizationController.delegate = self
    authorizationController.presentationContextProvider = self
    authorizationController.performRequests()
}

extension ViewController: ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate {
    func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithAuthorization authorization: ASAuthorization) {
        if let appleIDCredential = authorization.credential as? ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential {
         //here is credentials . 
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController: ASAuthorizationControllerPresentationContextProviding {
    func presentationAnchor(for controller: ASAuthorizationController) -> ASPresentationAnchor {
        return self.view.window!
    }
}
```

**Step2**:

create button

```
    let authorizationButton = ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton()
    authorizationButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleAuthorizationAppleIDButtonPress), for: .touchUpInside)
```

**Step3**

```
@objc
func handleAuthorizationAppleIDButtonPress() {
    let appleIDProvider = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider()
    let request = appleIDProvider.createRequest()
    request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]
    
    let authorizationController = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: [request])
    authorizationController.delegate = self
    authorizationController.presentationContextProvider = self
    authorizationController.performRequests()
}
```

**Availability** : *iOS 13 or higher*

**Demo Application**: A complete working demo application with keychain integration available on Github - https://github.com/developerinsider/Sign-In-with-Apple-Demo

**Note:** I will update answer with more and more useful information soon.

Hope it is helpful .

Comment: @vineet-choudhary The demo code is very useful but what about verifying signed in user? Is it required in native iOS app? I am referring to this post. https://blog.curtisherbert.com/so-theyve-signed-in-with-apple-now-what/

Comment: Yes. It required a native iOS app.

Comment: but what does this mean "After all, while operating on-device we can trust Apple's APIs not to lie to us, but as soon as we send this data to the server we need a way for said server to verify that someone isn't spoofing a user string. Normally you use the users' password for verification that they can access a given account, but we don't have that anymore." i am using hosted Parse server as backend. Do i have to implement verification? Any idea how?

Comment: @Prashant Tukadiya there is no way apple provides mechanism for logout, so that we need to handle by self.

Comment: curious is this works for existing applications? How would one manage old signups with this process?